# How to inject .less files with parameters to the less parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, less

How can I inject `.less` files with parameters to a less parser (less.js compiler) dynamically by creating an instance of the parser?

I have different themes. The user can select any theme. When the user selects a theme, I want to compile the associated `.less` file with proper parameters in the client side.

```
function writeCSS(color,other) {
    var lessCode = '';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            var options = {}
            lessCode = xmlhttp.responseText;
            less.render(lessCode, options, function (error, output) {
            if (!error) {
                $("style").append(lessCode.css);
            }
            else document.getElementById('lesscode').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">' + error + '</span>';
            });
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Content/Style.less?baseColorTheme='222222'&otherTheme='222222'&direction='ltr'", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could share some part of your code.

Comment: this is code sample of my suggestion  with some static  parameters @TGrif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main approaches. Usually `.less` files are pre-complied to CSS as part of the "asset pipeline." This process is overseen with build automation or scripts, the details of which vary by language and toolset. The user selecting a new theme would change the site's CSS link to a precompiled CSS file. With jQuery, assuming a stylesheet link like:

```
<link id="theme-css" rel="stylesheet" href="theme1.css">
```

The change would be as simple as:

```
var newTheme = 'theme2.css';
$('#theme-css').attr('href', newTheme);
```

A working example of a CSS theme changer [is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLb2MqGht3jEiOA9bCSm?p=preview).

But if you don't want to establish an asset pipeline to pre-compile your Less files into equivalent CSS, you can do almost the same thing on the fly. The trick is to load the `less.js` library as a script, and then do a little more work to trigger a change in theme:

```
var newTheme = 'theme2.less';
$('style[id^=less]').remove();
$('#theme-css').attr('href', newTheme);
less.refresh();
```

The first and third lines are almost identical. The new second line is necessary to remove the CSS stylesheets that `less.js` will add as compiled versions of your `.less` assets. The final line manually triggers a `less.js` run.

A running version of a Less-based theme changer [is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AdySjFxs3CgDYqkHVM62?p=preview).

As the online Less compilers demonstrate, you can take arbitrary Less code and compile it on the fly. For theme setting, however, it's generally sufficient to allow switching between a known set of source files. This at least reduces the need to handle the error conditions that arise if the Less source is not well-formed or compilable.